# Is there a way to prevent numeric entities being expanded in a XmlDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I'm working in C# 3.5.

I have a XML document that contains a character entity within an element's value. The reference is 
 (LF). I do not want this expanded out into an actual linefeed, I want it to remain as an entity. This is because the commercial tool that processes the XML requires the LF to be represented as an entity, not an actual LF.

However, if I pass it anywhere near an XmlReader, it gets converted. So I switched to a StreamReader, but then it gets converted by XmlDocument.Load & XmlDocument.LoadXml.

I've tried setting the XmlResolver to null, prohibiting DTDs, and all sorts, but I'm unable to get the document to leave the entities alone.

Any ideas? I'm going to bodge this by munging the content on both ends with some double escaping, but I'd like to know if there's a correct way of doing this.

(The reason it has to be Xml-ised at all is because it's being sent via a webservice as an XmlNode....and I can't change the API.)

Comment: How does the "commercial tool that processes the XML" want it passed in?

Comment: Our own tool is consuming our web service, and writing out a file, which the commercial tool then loads. This is how I can get away with the double escaping bodge. I'd rather not have a caveat for other consumers of the web service though, I just want them to be able to plonk the XmlNode out to disk and be done with it. I do prefer a note about the XmlWriter though suggested by Robert's answer over my bodge. I'll have a look when I'm back in the office with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an `XmlWriter` with an `XmlWriterSettings` object whose `NewLineHandling` property is set to `NewLineHandling.Entitize`, and write the XML to a string.  That'll get you a string containing entities instead of LF characters.

Comment: I've just tried using an XmlWriter as you describe to spit out my XmlDocument to a StringBuilder, but I'm still getting a newline rather than an entity. The XmlDocument, coming from the SOAP call, has a physical newline rather than the escaped entity, if that helps.

Comment: My bad; `Entitize` turns `\r` into `&#D;` and leaves `\n` alone.  Indeed, the `XmlReader` turns `&#A;` into `\r` no matter what.  The `XmlReader` automatically converts `&#A;` into `\r`, so any string that you parse will have that entity replaced with the actual character.  But that's how XML parsers are supposed to work.  So why does the tool that you're using not support XML?

Comment: ...because it's Microsoft Excel.

Comment: Today I learned that Microsoft doesn't use an `XmlReader` to read XML into Excel.  It's fantastically stupid to have to do this, but you can get Excel to handle `\n` in cell content properly if the value is saved as CDATA.